# striplines() not working when using finditer python

Tags: python, regex, string, multiline

I am trying to convert a multiline string to a single list which should be possible using splitlines() but for some reason it continues to convert each line into a list instead of processing all the lines at once. I tried to do it out of the for loop but doesnt seem to have any effect. I need the lines as a single list to use it another function. Below is how I get the multiline into a single variable. What am I missing???

```
multiline_string_final = []
for match_multiline in re.finditer(r'(^(\w+):\sThis particular string\s*|This particular string\s*)\{\s(\w+)\s\{(.*?)\}', string, re.DOTALL):
    multi_line_string = match_multiline.group(4)
    print multiline_string
```

This last print statement prints out the strings like this:

```
blah=0; blah_blah=1; Foo=3;
blah=4; blah_blah=5; Foo=0;
```

However I need:

```
['blah=0; blah_blah=1; Foo=3;''blah=4; blah_blah=5; Foo=0;']
```

I understand it has to be something with the finditer but cant seem to rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new problem *also* has nothing to do with `finditer`. (Also, your code is still not an MCVE, you still haven't shown us the sample input data, etc., making it harder to help you.)

From this desired output:

> ['blah=0; blah_blah=1; Foo=3;''blah=4; blah_blah=5; Foo=0;']

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is to get a list of the matches, instead of printing out each match on its own. That isn't a valid list, because it's missing the comma between the elements,* but I'll assume that's a typo from you making up data instead of building an MCVE and copying and pasting the real output.

Anyway, to get a list, you have to build a list. Printing things to the screen doesn't build anything. So, try this:

```
multiline_string_final.append(multiline_string)
```

Then, at the end—not inside the loop, only after the loop has finished—you can print that out:

```
print multiline_string_final
```

And it'll look like this:

```
['blah=0; blah_blah=1; Foo=3;',
 'blah=4; blah_blah=5; Foo=0;']
```

---

<sub>* Actually, it *is* a valid list, because adjacent strings get concatenated… but it's not the string you wanted, and not a format Python would ever print out for you.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the `finditer`, it's that you're doing the wrong thing:

```
for line in multiline_string:
    print multiline_string.splitlines()
```

If `multiline_string` really is a multiline string, then `for line in multiline_string` will iterate over the characters of that string.

Then, within the loop, you completely ignore `line` anyway, and instead `print multiline_string.splitlines())`.

So, if `multiline_string` is this:

```
abc
def
```

Then you'll print `['abc\n', 'def\n']` 8 times in a row. That's not what you want (or what you described).

What you want to do is:

- split the string into lines
- loop over those lines, not over the original un-split string
- print each line, not the whole thing

So:

```
for line in multiline_string.splitlines():
    print line
```

Comment: Same result when I do that. Just to make sure, I should do the for loop after I print the multiline string or outside that?? Also, my multiline string is already "multiple lines"  so why do you split the string into lines? I mean it is already split into multiple lines...

Comment: @Doodle: The `splitlines` method splits a single multi-line string into a list of separate single-line strings. (Also, why were _you_ calling it in your code?) The reason you might want such a list is so that you can loop over it with `for line in …`, exactly as you were trying to do.

Comment: I called it so that it will loop through each line. Also, the one you suggested, prints out only one line. not all the lines within a list. My outpu was: abc thats it.

Comment: Even when I do the loop seperate I get it to print only thh first line.

Comment: Hi I tried the .append(line) and it seems to give what I want but it prints out every value that it builds to give me the result. What could be wrong??

Comment: @Doodle: You can't "loop through each line" if you don't have a list of separate lines to loop through beforehand. It might help you to write a stripped-down program, with hardcoded inputs, and either add a bunch of `print` calls (and make sure to print out the `repr` of your strings), or run it in the debugger or an interactive visualizer, so you can see what you actually have at each point and understand what's happening.

Comment: @abarnet I think eventhough it prints out as multiple lines may be it is not reasing as multiline string. I really cant figure out whats wrong!!! I tried your method to  print out every step of the way and I removed some code which were redundant and updated the question..